# How to send JSON object from spring controller to javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I need to send JSON object from spring controller to javascript and recieve it with ajax. Is there someone who knows how to do it?

Comment: It doesn't make sens to say that you wan't to send JSON object from spring to Javascript and recevie it with Ajax.The data format is accessible through a web service created with spring and can we accessed with whatever client you want.It can be Ajax with Javascript , CURL,etc...

Comment: Check this : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/springmvc/springmvc_json.htm and then you can access data from endpoint.For ajax you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch or https://github.com/axios/axios to grab data through ajax http request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways you can call `Spring` rest service from `javascript`. You can choose pure `javascript` using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) , [jQuery Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) , [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) etc. It really depends on you requirements. You can look at individual link for more details. Here is one simple example using `jQuery Ajax`.

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    url:"/your-url"
    type:"GET",
    data:inputData,
    dataType: "json"

});

//Handle a successful call to data service
jqxhr.done(function( data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    // your code for success
});

//Handle an unsuccessful call to data service
jqxhr.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    // your code to handle fail     

});
jqxhr.always(function () {
    //your code
}); 

});
```